# Socket recv() function

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2

In c++, in windows OS, on the recv() call for TCP socket  , if the socket connection is closed somehow, the recv() will return immediately or will it hang?

What would be result(immediately returns or hangs)  in the blocking and non blocking socket?
I am using socket version 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: posix sockets ?

Comment: There is no `recv()` in standard C++, so until your specify the network API used, your question will be incomplete and not helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

[As documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv) depending of how the connection was closed it should more or less immediately with a return value of `SOCKET_ERROR` in a non graceful case and set `WSAGetLastError` to one of the possible reasons like `WSAENOTCONN` or would just return `0` in the graceful connection close scenario. This would be the same between blocking and nonblocking sockets.

> If the socket is connection oriented and the remote side has shut down the connection gracefully, and all data has been received, a recv will complete immediately with zero bytes received. If the connection has been reset, a recv will fail with the error WSAECONNRESET.

However, since I know the Windows API does not always work as documented, I recommend to test it.

Answer (score 0):

If your `recv()` is based on BSD - as almost all are - it will return immediately if the connection is closed (per the local side's status), regardless of whether the socket is blocking or non-blocking.

Comment: It would hang if the connection was not closed but left hanging by the other side though and it was a blocking socket (although that is a bit out of the scope of the question).

Comment: @SimonDoppler: all such calls works from the perspective of the local side / of course there's a delay for the local status to reflect whatever's just happened on the other end, and it may be long.

Answer (score 0):

`recv()` will return 0 upon a *graceful* disconnect, ie the peer shutdown its end of the connection and its socket stack sent a `FIN` packet to your socket stack.  You are pretty much guaranteed to get this result immediately, whether you use a blocking or non-blocking socket.

`recv()` will return -1 on any other error, including an *abnormal* connection loss. 
You need to use `WSAGetLastError()` to find out what actually happened.  For a lost connection on a blocking socket, you will usually get an error code such as `WSAECONNRESET` or `WSAECONNABORTED`.  For a lost connection on a non-blocking socket, it is possible that `recv()` may report an `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error immediately and then report the actual error at some later time, maybe via `select()` with an exception `fd_set`, or an asynchronous notification, depending on how you implement your non-blocking logic.

However, either way, you are NOT guaranteed to get a failure result on a lost connection in any timely manner!  It MAY take some time (seconds, minutes, can even be hours in *rare* cases) before the OS deems the connection is actually lost and invalidates the socket connection.  TCP is *designed* to recover lost connections when possible, so it has to account for temporary network outages and such, so there are internal timeouts.  You don't see that in your code, it happens in the background.

If you don't want to wait for the OS to timeout internally, you can always use your own timeout in your code, such as via `select()`, `setsocktopt(SO_RCVTIMEO)`, TCP keep-alives (`setsockopt(SO_KEEPALIVE)` or `WSAIoCtl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS)`), etc.  You may still not get a failure *immediately*, but you will get it sooner rather than later.